# Write all zeros from vector in R

Tags: r

I have one vector, example `x=c(0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6)`.
I want write out all zeros, all ones and next all numbers divisible by 2.
The output would look like this: `0 0 0 1 1 2 4 6` 
I don't know how to write out zeros and ones, because next I use `(which (x %% 2==0))`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `%%` and use `|`

```
x[x%%2==0 | x==1]
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 2 4 6
```

Comment: `!x%%s` is incredibly cryptic. It works if you read `%%` as “is divisible by” but since it’s normally read as “remainder of division by” or “mod”, I’d recommend the expression to be more explicit: `x %% 2 == 0`. Or, in this case, `x %% 2 != 0`.

Comment: What if I want write out only ones with vector?

Comment: @Robert Do you need only `1 1` as output.  In that case `x[x==1]`